# gcloud-python close connection

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

Is there a way in gcloud-python to close a connection? Currently, it seems that a connection is established and once it's done, it will sit there in `CLOSE_WAIT` and time out eventually. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Background: I have a server running that will open a new connection when a POST request comes in that writes to GCS. When looking at a `netstat`, there are ~ 40 connections (all to google) that are in `CLOSE_WAIT`.

Edit: I have looked through the docs and nothing seems to jump out at me

Answer (score 0):

It looks one can manually close the connection using `client.channel.close()` or `client._channel.close()` see [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15990#issuecomment-404287306), but that it only closes the connection made through `gRPC`, not the connections gcloud-python opens via `requests` [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15990#issuecomment-408511979).

I couldn't find much luck in fixing this issue using gcloud-python, but found success when using `subprocess` to call `gsutil`.

Don't know if that's an option for you, but let it be known that I've also struggling with this for the past couple while too! So hopefully after 2 years you've found reprieve or swept this issue under the rug :p